# Change Formview textboxes to proper case before inserting

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, case, formview

I know this is probably easy, but I just can't see the forrest for the trees, and the more trees I look at, well, you know.

I have an aspx web page with a formview designed in Visual Studio (asp.net 3.5)  that uses parameters to update my database.  Very often, someone puts their name or address in all caps through the web, and then submits it.  As there seems to be so many variables out there to consider when changing case, I'm thinking that when someone processes it, they would have a button that they could click that would change certain fields (ie firstname, lastname, street address) to the case that it should be therefore updating the sql fields (and yes, I want to update the database, not just the presentation).

I've tried using several scripts/things I found, but think since I know a little about a few, I'm getting them mixed up.  I've been stubborn enough to work on this for days, and am now running behind!  Please help!

Code is:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:techpreppetitionConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT FirstName, LastName, ContactID FROM test ORDER BY LastName"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE test SET LastName = @LastName,FirstName =@FirstName WHERE (ContactID = @ContactID)">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ContactID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ContactID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
    Width="750px" AllowPaging="True" DefaultMode="Edit">
    <EditItemTemplate>
       <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    First Name<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>' />
                    </td>
                <td>  &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    Last<br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>' />
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />

        <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
            Text="Update" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
            CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a sql user defined function that takes the string input and returns the formatted string. You use this function before you insert/update your fields.

E.g. [InitCap user defined function](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/initcap.aspx).

**Edit 1:**

Check this [InitialCaps](http://blog.madhukar4e.com/2008/04/javascript-initcaps-trimstring.html) in javascript:

Here is a sample I put together to use it:

```
$(function() { 
            $(".txtInfo").blur(function() {
                $(this).val(InitialCaps($(this).val()));
            });
         });
        function InitialCaps(theString) {
            theString = theString.toLowerCase();
            theString = theString.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + theString.substring(1, theString.length);

            var i = 0;
            var j = 0;
            while ((j = theString.indexOf(" ", i)) && (j != -1)) {
                theString = theString.substring(0, j + 1) + theString.substr(j + 1, 1).toUpperCase() + theString.substring(j + 2, theString.length);
                i = j + 1;
            }
            return theString;
        }

 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="txtInfo"></asp:TextBox>
```

It is using jquery to call the function on textbox blur.

Also if you find a better function you simply replace a call to that function i.e.

instead of $(this).val(InitialCaps($(this).val()));

you do $(this).val(YourInitialCaps($(this).val()));

**Edit 2:**

Ok I see. See my updated code. I added attribute CssClass="txtInfo" to the Textbox and get the reference to the TB in jquery using class selector.

Comment: That looks very promising, and I'm sure I'll use it somewhere, even if not here.  Perhaps I should be clearer also in saying a function that just updates the text field, so that when the 'update' button is clicked (that has already been designed and uses @variables) it updates to the proper case.  I kinda get the idea o what needs to happen, but don't know how it should look!

Comment: How you define "proper case"? I think then you convert that function to javascript and upon your input blur run that function i.e. everything will be taken care on client-side and when you receive the input it will already in proper format and so will be updated accordingly.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I need.  And if I knew how to do that, I'd be done!  ;-)

Comment: A clue! I noticed that I could never get any of the scripts I tried to recognize the textbox. I tried using a textbox outside of the formview, and it recognized it.   So back to the code -listed above- my textbox is inside of a formview variable.  Running it now says it's not declared.  How should it be declared where it can be recognized within the JS?

Comment: GBS, you ROCK!  I've been trying to get this done for DAYS!  I installed jquery and used your code, and viola!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? It will convert text into title case:
C#

```
TextInfo UsaTextInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
//Return title case
return UsaTextInfo.ToTitleCase(txt);
```

Theres also a javascript library that will do it, so you can use onblur to format the text.
http://individed.com/code/to-title-case/

Comment: I had looked at this, but it's my understanding that the totitlecase doesn't work with All Caps, which a lot of people are entering.